# How to find the total number of recursive calls?

Tags: java, recursion, math, methods

So I already computed the power of a number using recursion in Java, but I also wanted to print out the total number of recursive calls. For example, I treated my base value as 2 and my exponent as 9 and got the accurate result, but I got the total of 10 recursive calls and it should be 5. I not sure if I need to add another condition such if the exponent number is even or odd. Can anyone show what am I missing in the power function method because I have been stuck for a while?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Power1 {
   public static int count = 0;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // prompt the user to enter the base and exponent values
      // count = total number of recursive calls
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   
      System.out.print("Please enter the base value: ");
      double base = scanner.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Please enter the non-negative integer exponent value: ");
      int exp = scanner.nextInt();
      
      
      // call the power method
      double result = power(base, exp);
      
      // print out the result
      System.out.println(base + " raised to the power of " + exp 
                         + " is: " + result);
      // print out the total number of recursive calls
      System.out.println("A total of " + count + " recursive calls "
                         + "were made to the power method.");
   }
   
   static double power(double base, int exp) {
      count++;
      // base case:
      if (exp == 0) 
         return 1;
      
      else 
          return base * power(base,exp-1);
      
   }
}
```

Comment: why would it be 5? It gets called 10 times if `exp` is 9. Maybe you need another algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track with the odd and even. Was that a hint that was given to you?

You need to make use of the fact that `b^(x+y) == b^x * b^y`

You are currently splitting exp into `1` and `exp-1`, and using the those two values as your x and y.

But, that is the slowest possible way to do it. Choose numbers that are closer together.  Such as `exp / 2` and `exp - exp/2`  (assuming truncation). Of course, you need a special case for exp = 1 in that case.

EDIT:
Your question is really about algorithms. Why 10 calls when it could be fewer? Somebody told you it can be done in 5, and it can.

so, here we go in pseudo code, mostly because this is a fun algorithm to explore.

```
pow(base, exp) {

  if (exp == 0) return 1;
  else if (isOdd(exp)) {
    var val = pow(base, (exp - 1)/2);
    return base * val * val;
  } 
  else {
    var val = pow(base, exp/2);
    return val * val;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is only a hint to get you further along. You should be able, using the odd or even strategy, to break any number into either 2 or 3 pieces.   1 + 4 + 4 is 9.  2 + 2 = 4,  1 + 1 = 2

Comment: I was trying to follow the recursive definition and use three conditions where power(base,exp) = 1 if exp = 0, power(base,exp) = base * power(base,(exp-1)/2)^2 if exp >= 1 is odd, and power(base,exp/2)^2 if exp>=1 is even. I tried to implement them in power function, but I kept getting the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the first call is not a recursive call.
A call from within the method is a recursive call.

So, initializing `count` with `-1` will reduce that initial increment.

If it helps, try printing out the values for each call; it might provide a better visual of the process.

```java
static int count = -1;
static double power(double base, int exp) {
    count++;
    if (count != 0) System.out.printf("call %,d, exp= %,d%n", count, exp);
    return exp != 0 ? base * power(base, --exp) : 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the main method or power function?

Comment: A recursive call is when you are calling a method from within itself, so the initial call of `power` is not a recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a little more careful with your `power()` method. Compare this slightly different version of your method with your own, and compare it to the recursive definition you've been provided.

> 1. x<sup>0</sup> = 1
> 2. x<sup>n</sup> = x * x<sup>n-1</sup> for n odd, n>0
> 3. x<sup>n</sup> = (x<sup>n / 2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, n even, n>0

```java
public class Power1 {
    public static int count = 0;
    static double power(double base, int exp) {
        count++;
        // base case:
        if (exp == 0)
            return 1;

       if ((exp % 2) == 1) {
           return base * power(base, exp - 1);
       } else {
           double squareRoot = power(base, exp / 2);
           return squareRoot * squareRoot;
       }
    }
}
```